# Match request path against @PathVariable string?

Tags: java, regex, spring-boot, spring-mvc

On my controller class I have a typical `@RequestMapping` annotation with placeholders for `@PathVariable` annotations:

```
@RequestMapping("/customer/{id}/{whatever}")
public class CustomerController {
    @GetMapping
    public Customer getCustomer(@PathVariable final int id, @PathVariable final String whatever) {...}
}
```

**Now I need to match a `@RequestMapping` pattern-string like `/customer/{id}/{whatever}` against a real path like `/customer/1234/xyz`. As a result I need to know that `id` is `1234` and `whatever` is `xyz`.**

Are there any utility methods which can do this? (I need a generic solution, not the regular expression for the path above.)

Answer (score 1):

I tried to solve it with regular expressions but I think it is not very stable and will fail for special cases:

```
protected static Map<String, String> matchPath(String pathPattern, String path) {
    final Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\{([^\\/\\}]+)\\}").matcher(pathPattern);
    List<String> keys = matcher.results().map(x -> x.group(1)).toList();
    final String newRegex = matcher.replaceAll("([^\\/\\}]+)");

    final Matcher newMatcher = Pattern.compile(newRegex).matcher(path);
    newMatcher.find();
    final List<String> values = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, newMatcher.groupCount()).mapToObj(i -> newMatcher.group(i)).toList();

    return IntStream.range(0, keys.size()).boxed().collect(Collectors.toMap(keys::get, values::get));
}
```

Test:

```
@Test
void matchPath() {
    final Map<String, String> results = matchPath("/customer/{id}/{whatever}", "/customer/1234/xyz");
    
    assertThat(results.size(), is(2));
    assertThat(results.get("id"), is("1234"));
    assertThat(results.get("whatever"), is("xyz"));
}
```

First I find all "keys" and replace the {...} placeholders with the `"([^\\/\\}]+)"` expression.
This gives me a new regular expression which I use to match find the values.

But I am not very happy with this handmade solution...

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain more about what you are exactly trying to do...?

Because as per my understanding u don't wanna use @pathvariable annotation.

Also, you can do the same thing with @Requestparam annotation.

Like below:
/customer?id=1234&whatever=xyz

And in the controller you can use as @RequestParam(name = "id" int id) and @RequestParam(name = "whatever" String whatever)

Comment: Thanks four your answer. Please see my solution for better understanding. The question is not really about the annotations but about matching the strings. (I only explained where the strings with the {...} come from.)

Comment: It sounds not as an answer first. If you need more Information write better a comment first.